# Haskell equivalent of Kotlin's invariant types

Tags: kotlin, haskell, functional-programming, data-kinds, jenetics

In Kotlin i can do

```
sealed class Substance {
    object Uranus : Substance()
    object Mercury: Substance()
    object Ammonia : Substance()
}

data class DangerousBox<T : Substance>(val item: T)

fun main() {
    val uranus = DangerousBox<Substance.Uranus>(Substance.Uranus)
    val mercury: DangerousBox<Substance.Mercury> = uranus
}
```

Now i have invariant types `DangerousBox<Substance.Uranus>, DangerousBox<Substance.Mercury>` etc., so sample above would't compile.

How make it in Haskell?

Ideally i would like to have types

```
uranus :: DangerousBox Uranus
uranus = DangerousBox Mercury
```

and this sample musn't comlie too.

I tried to achieve it in the following ways:

1. Modular constraint.
   I have module

```
module Sample.Types.Boxes
  ( Substance(..)
  , dangerousBox
  , VDangerousBox {- no Con-}
  ) where

data Substance
  = Uranus
  | Mercury
  | Ammonia
  deriving (Show)

data VDangerousBox a =
  VDangerousBox Substance
  deriving (Show)

dangerousBox :: Substance -> VDangerousBox Substance
dangerousBox a = VDangerousBox a
```

Clients of module can use only dangerousBox, but here i have jeneric in relation to Substance:

```
uranus :: VDangerousBox Substance
uranus = dangerousBox Uranus
```

2. Data kinds

```
data DangerousBox :: Substance -> * where
  DangerousBox :: Substance -> DangerousBox a

uranus :: DangerousBox Uranus
uranus = DangerousBox Uranus

mercury :: DangerousBox Mercury
mercury = uranus {- it's ok, it dosn't compile -}
```

But in this case the following case will compile:

```
mercury :: DangerousBox Mercury
mercury = DangerousBox Ammonia
```

I understand that i received equivalent for

```
data Box<T : Substance>(val value: Substance)
```

in term of Kotlin generics it.

It's no real case, it is only of "academic" interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, given a particular choice of substance, there isn't any other information to be contained in the box (at least in your Kotlin code), I'd first consider just omitting it entirely:

```hs
import Data.Kind (Type)  -- preferred version instead of the old *

data DangerousBox :: Substance -> Type where
  DangerousBox :: DangerousBox a

uranus :: DangerousBox Uranus
uranus = DangerousBox
```

Then the `mercury = DangerousBox Ammonia` problem can't even arise, because the `DangerousBox` value constructor doesn't take *any* arguments.

If for some reason you do need an actual value representing the tag-type, then this should not be the tag itself as a `Type`-value, because in that view `Uranus`, `Mercury` and `Ammonia` are all the same type. Instead, you should use what's normally called the *singletons* of these types. You could have them [auto-generated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons), or define them manually:

```hs
data SubstanceSing :: Substance -> Type where
  UranusS :: SubstanceSing 'Uranus
  MercuryS :: SubstanceSing 'Mercury
  AmmoniaS :: SubstanceSing 'Ammonia
```

Now `UranusS` corresponds to your Kotlin `Substance.Uranus` when appearing on the value-level. Your box type then becomes

```hs
data DangerousBox :: Substance -> Type where
  DangerousBox :: SubstanceSing a -> DangerousBox a
```

Comment: The `SubstanceSing` singleton is equivalent to [`TypeRep @Substance`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#t:TypeRep) with `pattern UranusS :: () => a ~ Uranus => TypeRep a; pattern UranusS <- (eqTypeRep (typeRep @Uranus) -> Just HRefl)`. This can have benefits over singletons, like the compiler generated instances and inclusion in base.